# How to add in controller in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How exactly do you do arithmetic operations in the controller?

I've tried this

```
def choose
  rand_id = rand(Gif.count)
  @gif1 = Gif.first(:conditions => [ "id >= ?", rand_id])
  @gif2 = Gif.first(:conditions => [ "id >= ?", rand_id])
  if @gif1.id == @gif2.id
    @gif2 = Gif.first(:order => 'Random()')
  end
  total = @gif1.votes+@gif2.votes
  number_one = @gif1.votes/total*100
  number_two = @gif2.votes/total*100
  @gif1.update_attribute(:votes, number_one)
  @gif2.update_attribute(:votes, number_two)
end


class Gif < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :default_agree_count

  def default_agree_count
    self.agree = 1
    self.votes = 1
  end
  VALID_REGEX = /http:\/\/[\S]*\.gif$/
  attr_accessible :link, :votes, :agree
  acts_as_votable
  validates :link, presence: true, format: {with: VALID_REGEX}, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
end
```

However, it says that +, /, * are all unknown operators. I've also tried doing them within like such @gif1.agree = '@gif1.votes+1' with and without '. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the datatype of votes?

Comment: whats the exact Ruby error?

Comment: undefined method `/' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation

Comment: what is the association between Git and Votes model? Also post your schema

Comment: Git has a double called votes

Comment: are you sure @gif1 is not empty?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are using [Acts As Votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) gem.
Basically it works as follows:

```
@post = Post.new(:name => 'my post!')
@post.save

@post.liked_by @user
@post.votes.size # => 1
```

So try replacing `.votes` with `.votes.size` in your code.

E.g.:

```
total = @gif1.votes.size + @gif2.votes.size
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to `@ilyai's` answer (which I `+1`'d) (I don't have much experience with the `Acts As Votable` gem), you can perform any calculations you want in your controllers

Here's some refactoring for you:

[`.first`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-first)

```
def choose
  Gif.update_votes
end


class Gif < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :default_agree_count

  def default_agree_count
    self.agree = 1
    self.votes = 1
  end

  def self.update_votes
     rand_id = rand count #-> self.count?
     gif = where("id >= ?", rand_id)

     gif1 = gif[0]
     gif2 = gif[1]

     if gif1.id == gif2.id
         gif2 = where(order: 'Random()').first
     end

     total = (gif1.votes) + (gif2.votes)

     number_one = ((gif1.votes /total) * 100)
     number_two = ((gif2.votes / total) * 100)

     gif1.update_attribute(:votes, number_one)
     gif2.update_attribute(:votes, number_two)
  end

  VALID_REGEX = /http:\/\/[\S]*\.gif$/
  attr_accessible :link, :votes, :agree
  acts_as_votable
  validates :link, presence: true, format: {with: VALID_REGEX}, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
end
```